# Type juggling in function declarations

Tags: php

I'm just playing around here, my code:

```
<?php

function test(string $str, array $arr = array()) {
    echo $str;
}
test('something');
```

Which results in:

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to test() must be an instance of string, string given

I'm curious why I can precede `$arr` with `array` without any problems, but I cannot precede `$str` with `string`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String isn't a supported type hint as of yet

Edit: see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

and

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: Please link to the official documentation in your answers.